# send notification to particular devices by using device id

Tags: android, notifications, push

Hi I want to build an application  In my application i want to send the notification to particular devices.first i want to identify the device id then i want to send the notification based on device id because device id is unique for android.Now my question how can i send the notifications to particular device for this one i used parse.com for sending notification.by using parse.com I am sending notification to all the devices that one working properly.
.can anyone please tell me.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at
[[http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html][1]](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html%5d%5b1%5d)

You should use the Google Cloud Messaging for Android in order to send notification to multiple or single devices.

Once you register a device with your app, you'll be able to store the device ID.

Cheers.

Comment: but i want parse.com only i want to send the notification

Comment: without google account i want to send the notifications

Comment: eg.NDTV notifications